# How to fix a rocking toilet?

Tags: bathroom, toilet

Hello I am fairly new to the the whole DIY stuffs and since I don't live in that house anymore I do not have a picture of the problem. I did search online for the issue but all of them has the American toilet model (which has the out pipe under the toilet) which is different that mine and I already have a solution to fix it.

The actual problem I am facing is the screws aren't helps and the material which places the toilet in place is now dissolved or missing. I would like to know are there any kind of fills or material (other than cement) which I can use to fill the gap of the toilet and the ground to hold it firm. I thought of Gypsum Plaster but found out they are not good for moist area. Hope I conveyed the problem somewhat comprehensively. English isn't my first language so apologies for the clarity.

Edit [image]

This is roughly what I meant by the different design, as you can see the outflow pipe in attached with a sort of wall mount.

Comment: You could just shim the toilet then caulk around the base.  But you're talking about wanting to fill something in, just how uneven is this floor?  

Since you're not using a typical american toilet (didn't know other countries installed differently), a picture would definitely help.  Or even the type of toilet you're trying to fix.

Comment: If your toilet is "different" then an American toilet then we need to know what kind it is and how it is designed to be mounted or attached to the floor. More details please.

Comment: Details & photos of that material that is « dissolved » may help - you may have to repair that properly first...

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I am not sure if the caulk can hold it in place I was hoping to find an alternative for gypsum plaster which can be used in this scenario. Again I have no idea which kind of material is that sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the photo the toilet is bolted to the floor with two bolts, one on each side of the toilet. That is what holds the toilet in place not some caulk or material. If the floor is just slightly off, ( not flat ) then [toilet wedges](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Plumb-Pak-Plastic-Toilet-Hardware-Kit/3133325) will help to keep it from rocking.

[image]

*Photo source from the Lowe's link. You can find them online or at other home improvement stores.*

The wedges ( one or two ) are installed on one side, rock the toilet to see how it rocking then place the wedges in the void when the toilet is rocked all the way forward. I like to put them on the side less visible. Once you determine where they need to go loosen the bolts just slightly and snug the wedges in place and then tighten down the bolts so that the wedges are pinch in place. ( you can put a dab of caulk on them before you slip them in.)

Once the the bolts are tightened down you trim off the part of the wedge that sticking out and caulk around the base of the toilet.

*If the unevenness of the  floor is significant then you need to remove the toilet and take steps to level the floor. I do not know what the floor is made of so i can advise on that.*

Answer (score 0):

If the bolts to the floor don't hold anymore, the holes could be drilled out a little larger. Then use epoxy to fix new fasteners into the holes -- either studs standing up out of the holes, or threaded inserts if studs won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the toilet ,check the bolts replace with new ones . Have seen toilets not sit on floor and had to add shims to stop rocking. Uneven floors or defect in toilet.

Answer (score 0):

After replacing my son's toilet (which had a 1/8" to 1/4" gap all around) we wound up doing more remodeling later. In that later portion, we put down vinyl plank flooring over the tile and ran it under the toilet as well. Much to my surprise, it fixed the issue entirely.

If you're not looking to replace all the flooring, I would suggest looking around at discount centers and return areas for a box of vinyl plank and buy just one box. You can then use the vinyl plank to level the toilet. This is, of course, provided your *entire* toilet needs shims and not just one side.